# android: google glass custom(unlisted) voice command

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk, voice-recognition

I am trying to use custom(Unlisted) voice commands on google-glass but for some reason it doesn't want to work. The keyword I am trying to use is "NEXT", it was working before, I am not sure what has changed.The command is supposed to navigate to the next Card view. please see the xml below.

declaration

```
<string name="glass_voice_trigger">next</string>
```

Manifest

```
     <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.glassmenu.scroll"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.app.VoiceTriggers"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger_start" />
        </activity>
```

voiceTrigger.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger keyword="@string/glass_voice_trigger">
</trigger>
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me. Here is the value of my trigger keyword:

```
<string name="next_trigger">next</string>
```